# How to SQLAlchemy 4 queries at the same time?

Tags: python, sql, multithreading, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

im trying to perform 4 inserts at the same time. This is what im trying right now:

```
params = [
    [1, market_currency_id, add_party1, db],
    [1, pair_currency_id, - subs_party1, db],
    [2, market_currency_id, -subs_party2, db],
    [2, pair_currency_id, add_party2, db]
]  

cpu_count = os.cpu_count()  
with Pool( cpu_count ) as p:
    pu.db
    p.map(calculateBalances, params, 1)

def calculateBalances(params):
    user_id = params[0]
    currency_id = params[1]
    amount = params[2]
    db = params[3]
    _balance = Balance(user_id=user_id, currency_id= currency_id, amount=amount)
    db.add(_balance)
```

However, I get the following error:
`Can't pickle <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>: it's not the same object as sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session`

Comment: Inserting 4 records with multiprocessing would be an overkill I must say. The simplest approach could just iterate over the params list.

Comment: well this is actually a watered down example. but the main issue persists. I cant even run 4 simple queries, let alone my real 4 complex queries

Comment: You need to mention engine configurations include pool configuration as well in the post

Comment: Please provide what database you are using. Different databases have their own methods for large bulk inserts. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Another noteworthy thing: you should not usually share SQLA resources such as connections, the session, etc. between processes. Create them per process. In other words: even if you solved the pickling problem (passing a copy of  `Session` instance between processes), you'd just face new ones.

Comment: This is not an XY problem. I want to run N queries at the same time with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Then provide a proper [mcve]. The solution to your current issue is to create the SQLAlchemy constructs per process.